# Advanced CSS or Image?

Tags: image, css, styling

I have this idea of a div I'm trying to make. This is basically how it looks like.
How would you intend to make this? Or should I simply just use a image?
Redirect to URL is basically only a link to another website. This is also the top of a table. Or that's how I want it to be, but if any better ways, please tell!

```
          ______________
         /              \
        / REDIRECT TO URL\
_______/                  \________
```

How do you intend to do this?

Comment: I would use image, because it's a cross browser solution.

Comment: I guess that would be the fastest and maybe easiest way to do it. However do you have any idea on how this would be done with CSS. Is that fairly difficult?

Comment: I think it's not very difficult using `:before` and `:after`

Comment: ...But using an image is definitely a better approach?

Comment: Until we still have lots of users using older IE and other older browsers, yes it's better approach.

Comment: You Should use image because it's work in all browser

Comment: Why was this closed as “too localized”? Which of the criteria were satisfied?

Comment: I have no idea, it seems the "Big Dogs" are here to rule and actually I don't even know what too localized means. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this **pure CSS** solution..

HTML

```
<div class="topLeft"></div>
<div class="topMidd">Hello</div>
<div class="topRight"></div>
```

CSS

```
*{
  font-size:14px;
}
.topLeft{
  float:left;
  border-right:1em red solid;
  border-top:2em transparent solid;
  width:0;
  height:0;
}
.topMidd{
  float:left;
  background:red;
  height:2em;
  line-height:2em;
  padding:0 2em;
}
.topRight{
  float:left;
  border-left:1em red solid;
  border-top:2em transparent solid;
  width:0;
  height:0;
}
```

You can always play with the numbers to get how you want it. It's a cross-browser solution and it means you don't need to mess around making images.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CHEyW/2/)

Comment: Nice! You could make it more flexible by using the `em` unit instead of `px`, so that the dimensions would automatically adapt to the font size.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm glad you like, nice suggestion! Edit made.

Comment: Thanks for snippet, but I wont be using it either way. Check! ;=)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in css3 etc but would run into browser issues.

I would use an image for now, but if you want it to be nice and scalable for any text size I recommend laying out roughly like this.

```
<div class="holder">
<span class="block leftBlock"></span>
<span class="block innerBlock">REDIRECT TO URL</span>
<span class="block rightBlock"></span>
</div>
```

Then with your css

```
.holder{height:heightOFImage;}
.block{float:left;height:100%;display:block;}
.leftBlock{background-image:url("leftImg.png");width:20px;}
.centerBlock{background-image:url("centerImg.png");background-repeat:repeat-x;}
.rightBlock{background-image:url("rightImg.png"); width:20px;}
```

[image: img des]

This means you can use this with all different types off length strings

Comment: Thanks for nice example, and for great explanation, however I've changed my approach and I wont be making this thing either way, thanks though!